# I wanna add a small buttons bar down the note and when i do buttons dont appear why?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, tk-toolkit

am trying to make a notepad app and I wanted to add a small bar at the end with buttons to do custom stuff but when I try to add a button it doesn't appear on the program what did I do wrong?

here is the script

```
from gc import callbacks
import re
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
from turtle import right

root = Tk()
root.title('Notepad')
root.iconbitmap('C:/notes.ico')
root.geometry("500x500")

root.tk.call("source", "C:/Users/Hero/Documents/Visual Studio code/My project/azure.tcl")
root.tk.call("set_theme", "dark")

def change_theme():
    if root.tk.call("ttk::style", "theme", "use") == "azure-dark":
        root.tk.call("set_theme", "light")
    else:
        root.tk.call("set_theme", "dark")

style=ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('azure-dark')
style.configure("Vertical.TScrollbar", background="grey", bordercolor="black", arrowcolor="white")

scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical')
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')

text=Text(root, font=("Georgia, 24"), yscrollcommand=scroll.set, bg='#292929')
scroll.config(command=text.yview)
text.pack()

#button am talking about
fonts = ttk.Button(root, text='Size and Font', style='Accent.TButton')
fonts.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Update: It worked when i had the buttons at the top but at the bottom it doesn't show up

Comment: Why do you import `turtle`. Which button are you talking about. If you are not able to see any buttons then it could be because you restrict the geometry of the window.

Comment: am talking about the button of tkinter and i tried removing the restriction and restricting the text and nope it didnt work

Comment: The given code works fine for me

Comment: so the problem can be from my side right?

Comment: The text box is too tall for a window with size 500x500, so the bottom button is pushed out of the viewable area of window.  Set `height=10` to `Text(...)`, for example, will show the button.

Comment: @Real Swat. set this to root.geometry("500x900") and fonts.pack(side =ttk.tkinter.BOTTOM)

Comment: @acw1668. The fonts.pack() is default to top. So you cannot see it.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Yes I know, but it still be packed under the text box and so it is at the bottom vertically.

Comment: @acw1668 limiting the text box did it but can't I make it extend to the end leaving the buttons visible? so if I wanna resize the window it resizes the text box but leaves the buttons at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text box is too tall for a window with size 500x500, so the button below the text box is out of the viewable area of the window.

You can set the `width` and `height` options of the text box to a smaller values and use `text.pack(fill='both', expand=1`)` to expand the text box to fill the window:

```py
# set width and height to smaller values
text = Text(root, font=("Georgia, 24"), yscrollcommand=scroll.set, bg='#292929', width=1, height=1)
# then expand it to fill the window
text.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed by adding a frame then making it at the bottom then putting the button at this frame thanks everyone that tried to help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).